# Efficient heat diffusion implementation with varying coefficients

Tags: finite-difference, spectral-method, efficiency, heat-transfer

I have the following heat diffusion equation:
\begin{alignat}{3}
\partial_t u(t, \vec{x}) &= g(\vec{x})\Delta u(t,\vec{x}), &\quad& \vec{x} \in\Omega, \, t\in(0,\infty],\\
\partial_n u(t,\vec{x}) &= 0, &\quad& \vec{x}\in\partial\Omega,\, t\in(0,\infty], \\
u(0,\vec{x})&=f(\vec{x}), &\quad& \vec{x}\in\Omega.
\end{alignat}

I want to solve this on a regular grid, thus I use the finite difference method to discretise $\Delta$ with the Neumann boundary conditions with a matrix $-W$, and I discretise the functions $f, g, u(t)$ as the vectors $f,g\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u:\mathbb{R}^+_0\to \mathbb{R}^n$, defined on the grid with $n$ points. Setting $G=\operatorname{diag}(g)$ I can now rewrite the PDE as a system of ODEs:

$$\partial_t u(t) = -GWu(t), \quad u(0) = f.$$

The solution of this ODE at time $T$ is given as $u(T) = \exp(-TGW)f$. How would I go about implementing this efficiently in practice?

One option is of course to use the series expansion and truncate for a large enough $m$:
$$\exp(-TGW)f = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-TGW)^k}{k!}f \approx \sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{(-TGW)^k}{k!}f.$$

Another option is to use the eigendecomposition of $-GW = P\Lambda P^{-1}$ to compute the matrix directly:
$$\exp(-TGW) = P\begin{bmatrix} \exp(-T\lambda_1) & & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & \exp(-T\lambda_n) \end{bmatrix} P^{-1}.$$

However the latter sounds like a pretty bad deal compared to the equation with constant coefficients, since for the latter I have the eigendecomposition $-W = V \Lambda' V^T$ where I know the form of $V$ and $\Lambda'$ explicitly and there's even an $O(n\log n)$ algorithm for computing the application of $V$ and $V^T$ to a vector (it's a fast DCT-II and DCT-III transform). Is there any way the knowledge about $V$ and $\Lambda'$ can be used in the variable coefficients setting?

Edit: I guess I could set $u(t) = G^{1/2}v(t)$, and then I get (for $G$ invertible):
$$\partial_t G^{1/2} v(t) = -GWG^{1/2}v(t) \implies \partial_t v(t) = -G^{1/2}WG^{1/2} v(t).$$
Then at least I get a symmetric matrix, so the eigenvalue and eigenvectors may be computed more efficiently. On the other hand I am not sure whether there is an obvious way to relate $V$ and $\Lambda'$ to the eigendecomposition of $-G^{1/2}WG^{1/2}$.

Comment: How big is $n$ and how many $f$'s would you like to apply this to? If $n$ is large enough and you don't have many $f$'s then there are Krylov-based methods for computing matrix exponentials that would probably be pretty fast for this matrix

Comment: @whpowell96 Sometimes $n$ is small enough for to do the eigendecomposition directly, sometimes it is so large that there is no way I would be able to even store the eigendecomposition (maybe only the largest eigenvalues/vectors of it). The right hand side $f$ is only one. Do you have any suggestion for a Krylov-based algorithm for matrix exponentials? I wasn't even aware this existed, although it makes sense since generally I would use Arnoldi for the eigenvalues. Do you have any idea whether the knowledge of $V$ and $\Lambda'$ can somehow be leveraged here?

Comment: I'm not aware of state of the art methods but a description of approximating a matrix exponential matvec with an Arnoldi iteration is given in *On Krylov Subspace Approximations to the Matrix Exponential* by Hochbruck and Lubich. Also, I would double check your finite difference scheme, as spatially-varying diffusion coefficients are typically modeled as $\nabla\cdot(g\nabla u)$, not $g\nabla^2 u$. This is necessary to keep the operator Hermitian

Comment: If you end up using this suggestion, I will write it up as an answer but I can't offer much extra commentary other than I know it exists. I believe SotA involves adaptively updating/restarting the Krylov basis so the matrix exponential subproblems don't get too big

Comment: @whpowell96 Yes I am aware that spatially varying diffusion with diffusivity $g$ is written as $\nabla\cdot(g\nabla u)$, however in my case $g$ is not a diffusivity. So yes this is not symmetric, but as noted the system can be made symmetric by setting $u=G^{1/2}v$ and solving for $v$, so that's a non-issue as far as Arnoldi goes. I don't know what the SotA abbreviation refers to. Feel free to make your comments an answer.

Comment: The paper I linked is from the late 90s. SotA = state of the art

Comment: The solution of the heat equation in your question is formally correct, however, that is not how PDEs are usually propagated. Rather, you take one of the myriads of readily available integrators, see [here](https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqDocs/stable/solvers/ode_solve/). Propagating the PDE via the exponential is useful only in specific cases where the system is small enough to do the $O(n^3)$ computations and $O(n^2)$ storage. When you therefore resort to Krylov subspace methods and the like, you'll gain advantages over the general-purpose integrators in the link only for selected cases.

Comment: @davidhigh Thank you for the link, and I agree with you that one typically also discretises the time derivative. But I am not looking to discretise time in this specific case, that's why I wrote the matrix exponential.

Comment: What is your intention when you avoid the time discretization? In fact, solving an ODE is a standard technique in approximating the (action of the) matrix exponential. See e.g. the famous [*Nineteen Dubious Ways to
Compute the Exponential of a
Matrix*](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/ReadingSeminar/Papers/Moler03.pdf) paper.

Comment: @davidhigh Thank you for the resource. I am just studying different numerical solutions of the problem - I thought it was a good exercise to learn something new - I have studied Euler and Runge-Kutta methods, so that's not really new to me. I have both explicit and implicit Euler (with a CG solver for the steps) along with the spectral one for comparisons. I just found that, e.g. if I do the eigendecomposition, then the exponential handles the case $v(x) = \infty$ very gracefully and elegantly compared to the implicit and explicit Euler, where I have to be rather careful.

Comment: Is it the case $v(x)=\delta(x-x_0)$ which you mean by $v(x)=\infty$?

Comment: @davidhigh I misspoke, I meant to write $T=\infty$ or $g\equiv \infty$. I still cannot handle the spatially varying case where only some $g$ are infinite. I can approximate the solution with multistep implicit Euler by reparametrizing $g(x) = c(x)/(1-c(x))$, where $c(x)\in[0,1]$, $1$ corresponding to infinite $g(x)$, and moving the denominator to the other terms (I get a Laplace equation at points where $c(x)=1$): $(1-c)\partial_t u = c\Delta u$. For the spectral approach I would somehow have to find the eigendecomposition of $\lim_{g|_J\to\infty}GW$, where $J$ is the set where $c(x)=1$.